# How to scrape the data upto n levels using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and this is my first try in web scraping. Structure of the webpage fro which I am trying to scrape is following:

*level 0: Main company URL ---> level 1: several associated company URLs ----> level 2: each associated company URL in level 1 has many URLs linked ---> ... upto level n*

Right now I can scrape data upto level 1. But I want to do it upto n th level recursively. There should be a control like *max_depth* upto which I want to scrape.

I can not figure out how to do it.

Here is my spider which I wrote so far:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import * 

class NodeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'nodes'
  start_urls = ['https://www.zaubacorp.com/companysearchresults/DOIT-']
  base_url = 'https://www.zaubacorp.com/'
  
  custom_settings = {
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
    }


  def parse(self, response):
    search_links = response.xpath('//table[@id="results"]/tr/td/a[contains(@href,"company/DOIT-URBAN")]/@href').getall()
    page_list = search_links[1:]
    #url = search_links.pop(0) 
    check_list = []
    for url in search_links:
      print("func 1")      
      yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse_doit,meta={'page_list':page_list,
                                                                    'check_list':check_list
                                                                    })


  def parse_doit(self, response):
    print("func 2")
    check_list = response.meta['check_list']
    lnk = MainLink()

    lnk['name'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/p//text()').get()
    lnk['url'] = response.url
    lnk['address'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]//p[4]/text()').get()
    lnk['email'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]//p[1]/text()').get()
    lnk['director1'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="package1"]/td[2]//p//text()').get()
    lnk['director2'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="package2"]/td[2]//p//text()').get()
    
    dir1_same_co_list = response.xpath('//*[@id="accordion1"]/table[1]//td//p/a/@href').getall()
    dir2_same_co_list = response.xpath('//*[@id="accordion2"]/table[1]//td//p/a/@href').getall()        
    
    co_list = dir1_same_co_list + list(set(dir2_same_co_list)-set(dir1_same_co_list))
    dir_same_co_list = list(set(co_list)-set(check_list))
    check_list = check_list + list(set(dir_same_co_list)-set(check_list))


    page_list = response.meta['page_list']
    

    if dir1_same_co_list:
      next_url_dir = dir_same_co_list.pop(0)
      
      yield response.follow(url = next_url_dir, callback = self.parse_level_2, 
                                                   meta = {'name':lnk,
                                                           'url':lnk,
                                                           'address':lnk,
                                                           'email':lnk,
                                                           'director1':lnk,
                                                           'director2':lnk,
                                                           'dir_same_co_list':dir_same_co_list,
                                                           'page_list':page_list
                                                           })
    
  
  def parse_level_2(self,response):
    print("func 3")
    lnk = response.meta['name']
    lnk = response.meta['url']
    lnk = response.meta['address']
    lnk = response.meta['email']
    lnk = response.meta['director1']
    lnk = response.meta['director2']
    page_list = response.meta['page_list']
    #next_page = response.meta['next_page']

    level_2 = SecondaryLink()
    
    try:
      lnk['Company_Details_W_Same_Directors']
    except: 
      lnk['Company_Details_W_Same_Directors'] = []
    
    #for sub_link in dir1_same_co_list:
    level_2['Co_Name'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/p//text()').get()
    level_2['Co_url'] = response.url
    level_2['Address'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]//p[4]/text()').get()
    level_2['Email'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]//p[1]/text()').get()
    level_2['First_Director'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="package1"]/td[2]//p//text()').get()
    level_2['Second_Director'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="package2"]/td[2]//p//text()').get()
    
    lnk['Company_Details_W_Same_Directors'].append(level_2)

    dir_same_co_list = response.meta['dir_same_co_list']  

    print("===== start reading co list =====")

    if dir_same_co_list:
      
      next_url_dir = dir_same_co_list.pop(0)
      print("co list",len(dir_same_co_list))
      yield response.follow(url = next_url_dir, callback = self.parse_level_2, 
                                                 meta = {'name':lnk,
                                                         'url':lnk,
                                                         'address':lnk,
                                                         'email':lnk,
                                                         'director1':lnk,
                                                         'director2':lnk,
                                                         'dir_same_co_list':dir_same_co_list,
                                                         'page_list':page_list
                                                        })

    else:
      if page_list:
        print("next page loop")
        next_page = page_list.pop(0)
        next_page_url = next_page
        yield response.follow(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse_doit, meta={'name':lnk,
                                                                                 'url':lnk,
                                                                                 'address':lnk,
                                                                                 'email':lnk,
                                                                                 'director1':lnk,
                                                                                 'director2':lnk,
                                                                                 'next_page':next_page,
                                                                                 'page_list':page_list})

      else:
        yield lnk
```

and the *items.py* is following:

````
class MainLink(scrapy.Item):
  name = scrapy.Field()
  url = scrapy.Field()
  address = scrapy.Field()
  email = scrapy.Field()
  director1 = scrapy.Field()
  Company_Details_W_Same_Directors  = scrapy.Field()
  director2 = scrapy.Field()  
  pass

class SecondaryLink(scrapy.Item):
  Co_Name = scrapy.Field()
  Co_url = scrapy.Field()
  Address = scrapy.Field()
  Email = scrapy.Field()
  First_Director = scrapy.Field()
  Second_Director = scrapy.Field()
  pass ```


 Help is much appreciated
````

Comment: check_list part I have added later. For this, I am getting keyerror. This was added to remove the repetition in the company url list.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `DEPTH_LIMIT` in scrapy. Please see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-limit